# Replacement for mysql.proc in version 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am searching for a replacement for `mysql.proc` in MySql version 8.

Up to version 5.7 the definers for a particular schema can be changed in a single shot through the query

```sql
UPDATE mysql.proc SET definer = 'root@localhost' WHERE db = 'db name'
```

Is there any way to do this in version 8